# C#.net OpenFileDialog SaveFileDialog Test

Tags: c#, mocking, mstest

I have the following code that I am struggling to test. How can I go about mocking these to test? I am using MSTest

```
public bool SaveToFile(string content)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "GPL Files|*.gpl|Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Save GPL File";

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;

            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);
                return true; // Success
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                return false; // Failure
            }
        }
    }

    return false; // Dialog was canceled
}
public string? LoadFromFile()
{
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.Filter = "GPL Files|*.gpl|Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
        openFileDialog.Title = "Open GPL File";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

            try
            {
                string loadedText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                return loadedText;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null; // Return null to indicate failure
            }
        }
    }

    return null; // Dialog was canceled
}
```

I have had a dabble abstracting away the properties of the Dialog classes, but can't get things to work.

Comment: "I have had a dabble abstracting away the properties of the Dialog classes" how did you do that? Are you using interfaces? How are you mocking other dependencies in your unit tests? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073269/options-to-mock-openfiledialog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312666/unit-test-file-reading-method-with-openfiledialog-c-sharp

Comment: I tried using interfaces:
'public interface IFileDialog
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Filter { get; set; }
    DialogResult ShowDialog();
    string FileName { get; set; }
}'.
This is my first encounter where a dependency needs mocking, am new to c#